# INSERT INTO fails with no errors

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do an INSERT INTO with PHP and Mysql.

Here is the SQL Statement, which succeeds in PHPMyadmin:

```
INSERT INTO purchase_orders VALUES (
    DEFAULT, 
    '501',
    '80999',
    '149179',
    'EB-0408898',
    '1',
    'Thompson Center Barrel Encore 26\" Stainless Steel Fluted 35 Whelen 4767',
    '294.43',
    '4767',
    'UPS Ground',
    '11.61',
    'LA',
    'P',
    '1',
    '264.99', 
    DEFAULT, 
    DEFAULT
)
```

Here is my PHP statement running the SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO purchase_orders VALUES (
    DEFAULT, 
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($po_num)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($order_id)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($product_id)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($product_code)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($amount)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($product)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($price)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($mfg_code)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_method)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($shipping_cost)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($s_state)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($status)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($dist_code)."',
    '".mysql_real_escape_string($dist_cost)."', 
    DEFAULT, 
    DEFAULT)";
mysql_query($sql, $dbc);
echo mysql_errno($dbc) . ": " . mysql_error($dbc). "\n";
```

I am completely perplexed why the insert statement is not working with PHP.

I have tried this SQL code also with the same result...

```
INSERT INTO purchase_orders(po_num, order_id, product_id, product_code, amount, product, price, mfg_code, shipping_method, shipping_cost, s_state, status, dist_code, dist_cost) VALUES ('501','80999','149179','EB-0408898','1','Thompson Center Barrel Encore 26\" Stainless Steel Fluted 35 Whelen 4767','294.43','4767','UPS Ground','11.61','LA','P','1','264.99')
```

Comment: same with mysqli / pdo_mysql or is it just possible to use the default mysql extension? how is the table structure? is $dbc a resource?

Comment: can you echo the $sql statement before you call mysql_query, just to prove that part of the code is actually getting called?

Comment: That is what I an showing the the SQL code box above.

Comment: $dbc = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password);
if (!$dbc) {
    print"<pre>";
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    print"</pre>";
}

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `DEFAULT` in fields:

```
INSERT INTO purchase_orders (<colname1>,<colname2>,.....) VALUES ( '501','80999','149179','EB-0408898','1','Thompson Center Barrel Encore 26\" Stainless Steel Fluted 35 Whelen 4767','294.43','4767','UPS Ground','11.61','LA','P','1','264.99')
```

Instead use it like this by associating insert values to the columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just get it to insert the default values, you can set the values for those columns to null.  Like this:

```
INSERT INTO purchase_orders VALUES (null, '501','80999','149179','EB-0408898','1','Thompson Center Barrel Encore 26\" Stainless Steel Fluted 35 Whelen 4767','294.43','4767','UPS Ground','11.61','LA','P','1','264.99', null, null)
```

The database will figure out that it needs to put defaults in the columns where you asked for null.

Comment: INSERT INTO purchase_orders VALUES (NULL, '501','80999','149179','EB-0408898','1','Thompson Center Barrel Encore 26\" Stainless Steel Fluted 35 Whelen 4767','294.43','4767','UPS Ground','11.61','LA','P','1','264.99', NULL, NULL) - works in phpmyadmin, no go with PHP and still no error.

Comment: Does it always replace NULL with the default value, or only if the field has NOT NULL specified?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to insert anything to your DB? Does your `mysql_query($sql, $dbc);` portion of your code work?

There's no need to insert default values to your table, after all they are default values. Of course it's a nice reminder of your table structure but I'd leave that out.

Otherwise if you do like VIPIN JAIN suggested everything should work. Define the columns you're inserting values. You may leave the single quotes out from the query if the colum's data type is an integer.

Still it's odd you don't get any error message. Are you sure your database connection is working?

---

Update. Try this. Name the colums and remove the `real_escape_string()` function. Add it if this works or clean the variables before concatenating the query. If this doesn't work, double check the values and table structure for invalid values. Echo the values you're trying to assign to the `$sql` before and after the `real_escape_string()` function. Maybe the it has done something peculiar.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `purchase_orders` (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`,'";
$sql .= "`column5`,`column6`,`column7`,`column8`,`column9`,`column10`,";
$sql .= "`column11`,`column12`,`column13`,`column14`)";
$sql .= " VALUES ('{$po_num}','{$order_id}','{$product_id}',";
$sql .= "'{$product_code}','{$amount}','{$product}','{$price}',";
$sql .= "'{$mfg_code}','{$shipping_method}','{$shipping_cost}',";
$sql .= "'{$s_state}','{$status}','{$dist_code}','{$dist_cost}')";
```